# Non-uniform p-values from hoeffd function in Hmisc when data sets are independent

Tags: r, p-value, nonparametric

When using the function *hoeffd* in the CRAN package *Hmisc* I get unusual p-values for pairs of data sets that are independent. The function hoeffd is an implementation of [Hoeffding's $D$ statistic](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177730150). Given a pair of independent data sets, the p-value from the $D$ statistic [should be a uniform random variable.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value#Distribution) However, I get a distribution that looks uniform up to $0.4$, then the density spikes and decreases linearly to $1$.

Suppose I run the following code, which generates $10{,}000$ pairs of independent Gaussian data sets (each set of length $100$), calculates the p-value for the independence test on each of them, and then plots a histogram of the p-values:

```
library(Hmisc)
N = 10000
n = 100
set.seed(n)
pvals = numeric(N)
for (i in 1:N) {
    pvals[i] = hoeffd(rnorm(n), rnorm(n))$P[1, 2]
}
hist(pvals, freq = FALSE, main = paste("P-Values: n = ", n, sep = ""), xlab = "P-Values")
```

Then the output is
[image: Hoeffding's P-Values for a pair of 100 independent Gaussian observations]

Running the same simulation, but with each data set in each pair having $1{,}000$ observations:

```
N = 10000
n = 1000
set.seed(n)
pvals = numeric(N)
for (i in 1:N) {
    pvals[i] = hoeffd(rnorm(n), rnorm(n))$P[1, 2]
}
hist(pvals, freq = FALSE, main = paste("P-Values: n = ", n, sep = ""), xlab = "P-Values")
```

gives

[image: Hoeffding's P-Values for a pair of 1000 independent Gaussian observations]

It takes a long time to compute this with $n = 10{,}000$ but a pattern like this is still visible with a small number of simulations.

If you run the code above but replace

```
rnorm(n)
```

with, for example,

```
rexp(n, 1)
```

you get essentially the same results.

I'm assuming that this is due to the fact that the p-values are asymptotic approximations of the true p-values, [which is stated in the reference manual.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/Hmisc.pdf#page.149) But shouldn't the distribution look more uniform than this? Why do the p-values have this distribution?

I am using R version 3.5.2 ("Eggshell Igloo") on my Mac (but I get the same distribution on Windows) and I'm using Hmisc version 4.2-0.

Comment: An excellent question and well laid out, although we may not care as much whether a p-value should be 0.7 vs 0.9.  I hope you get some responses from those knowledgeable about how the null distribution approximation works with Hoeffding's test.